# Network partition detected in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have a RabbitMQ cluster with 3 nodes. The system is live and frequently there is a network partition error.

> Network partition detected
>
> Mnesia reports that this RabbitMQ cluster has experienced a network
> partition. There is a risk of losing data.

I want to receive an email notification when this event occurs in the RabbitMQ.

Is there a way to receive a notification from RabbitMQ if there is any network partition issue in the cluster?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can configure [prometheus](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html), and with it, you can integrate mail, alerts etc..

there is also a video about that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWISW6AwpOE

Answer (score 0):

frequently issue is not acceptable for rabbitmq.
so should avoid this situation.

in my case, if you using cluster with docker , met it frequently.
whilc change to normal installation. issue gone.